# french language encoding for charset utf-8 still has all the french accents java

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using utf-8 to parse my french text to html using jsoup. But still all the french accents and special characters are not encoded. 
For example `&` as `&amp;` etc.,

Answer (score 0):

As long as the output encoding for your HTML is also UTF-8, they wouldn't need to be, with the exception of `&amp;`, `&gt;` and `&lt;` of course.

Comment: I tried with ISO-8859-1 encoding and seems that the French accented text is working fine.